# Filter results in mongoDb based on status

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have an array like this

```
[
{
    "name": "CAMP-1",
    "status": "incomplete",
    "version": 3,
  },
  {
    "name": "CAMP-1",
    "status": "complete",
    "version": 2,
  },
  {
    "name": "CAMP-1",
    "status": "complete",
    "version": 1,
  },
  {
    "name": "CAMP-2",
    "status": "complete",
    "version": 2,
  },
{
    "name": "CAMP-2",
    "status": "incomplete",
    "version": 1,
  }
]
```

if the status of latest version is incomplete then both the latest  incomplete and complete versions should be returned.

if the status of the latest version is complete then only that version should be returned.

I tried to group by name and  status which  gives the latest version of incomplete and complete  object

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  "$sort": {
    "version": -1
  }
},
{
  "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "content": "$name",
      "status": "$status"
    },
    "status": {
      "$first": "$$ROOT"
    },
    "content": {
      "$first": "$$ROOT"
    }
  }
},
{
  "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": "$content"
  }
})
```

The  output which I get  is

```
[
{
    "name": "CAMP-1",
    "status": "incomplete",
    "version": 3,
  },
{
    "name": "CAMP-1",
    "status": "complete",
    "version": 2,
  },
  {
    "name": "CAMP-1",
    "status": "complete",
    "version": 1,
  },
{
    "name": "CAMP-2",
    "status": "incomplete",
    "version": 2,
  }
]
```

But the  expected  output is

```
[
{
    "name": "CAMP-1",
    "status": "incomplete",
    "version": 3,
  },
{
    "name": "CAMP-1",
    "status": "complete",
    "version": 2,
  },
{
    "name": "CAMP-2",
    "status": "complete",
    "version": 2,
  }
]
```

Can anyone please help on how to filter the data based on status?

Comment: I'm confused as to what you are asking. What do you mean by latest version?

Comment: So `'version': 2`, is latest in your comment example. correct? and when it is marked `'complete'` you only want `'version': 2` to show. correct?

Comment: yes thats  correct

Comment: if its marked incomplete then both  the  latest versions status =  incomplete and status = complete should be shown.

Comment: what if one is complete and the other is incomplete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- group by name
- find the max-complete version
- filter to keep the completed with the same version and the uncompleted with bigger version
- unwind and replace root

*For example for 1 name, if you have incomplete version  5 6 7 3 and complete 2 3 4 , you will get 5 6 7 incompletes and 4 complete.
If its not what you want exactly maybe with small changes you can get what you need.

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=625a1325f7e3c64c6511e193) (to see what each stage does put the mouse on its end)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$group": {"_id": "$name", "docs": {"$push": "$$ROOT"}}},
 {"$set": 
   {"max-complete": 
     {"$let": 
       {"vars": 
         {"c": 
           {"$filter": 
             {"input": "$docs",
              "cond": {"$eq": ["$$this.status", "complete"]}}}},
        "in": {"$max": "$$c.version"}}}}},
 {"$set": 
   {"docs": 
     {"$filter": 
       {"input": "$docs",
        "cond": 
         {"$or": 
           [{"$and": 
               [{"$gt": ["$$this.version", "$max-complete"]},
                 {"$eq": ["$$this.status", "incomplete"]}]},
             {"$and": 
               [{"$eq": ["$$this.version", "$max-complete"]},
                 {"$eq": ["$$this.status", "complete"]}]}]}}}}},
 {"$unwind": "$docs"},
 {"$replaceRoot": {"newRoot": "$docs"}}])
```